# Javafx ListView deleting ListCell item

Tags: java, listview, javafx

I'm trying to delete items in my ListView when delete Button is clicked, but it is not working and I can't figure it out.
Here is an Example of my Code for deleting an entry based on the instance "Student":

```
public void deleteButton(ActionEvent actionEvent) {

    if (notesListView.getSelectionModel().isEmpty()) {
        InfoModal.show("Bitte wählen Sie die zu löschende Notiz aus.");
        return;
    }

    boolean delete = ConfirmationModal.show("Soll die Notiz gelöscht werden?");
    if (delete) {
        Dao<Notepad, Integer> notepadDao = db.getNotepadDao();

        try {
            if (this.objectType instanceof Student) {
                Dao<StudentNotepad, Integer> studentNotepadDao = db.getStudentNotepadDao();
                for (StudentNotepad n : studentNotepadDao) {
                    if (notesListView.getSelectionModel().getSelectedItem().equals(n.getNotepad())) {
                        SceneManager.getInstance().getLoaderForScene(SceneType.NOTESTAB_WINDOW).
                                <NotesTabController>getController().notesListView.getItems().remove(n.getNotepad());
                        studentNotepadDao.delete(n);
                        notepadDao.delete(n.getNotepad());
                    }
                }
            }
        }
    }
}
```

This is how my ListView/ListCell is initiated:

```
public void setObject(Object object) {
    //Getting Object Type (Group, Groupage or Student)
    this.objectType = object;

    try {
        if (this.objectType instanceof Student) {
            ObservableList<Notepad> list = FXCollections.observableArrayList();
            for (StudentNotepad s : db.getStudentNotepadDao()) {
                if ((db.getLoggedInUser() == s.getNotepad().getUser()) && ((((Student) this.objectType).getId() == s.getStudent().getId()))) {
                    list.add(s.getNotepad());
                }
            }
            notesListView.setItems(list);
            notesListView.getItems().clear(); //not needed if list is definitly empty
            db.getStudentNotepadDao().queryForAll().stream()
                    .map(StudentNotepad::getNotepad)
                    .filter(n -> n.getUser().equals(db.getLoggedInUser()))
                    .forEach(notesListView.getItems()::add);
            notesListView.setCellFactory(new Callback<ListView<Notepad>, ListCell<Notepad>>() {
                public ListCell<Notepad> call(ListView<Notepad> param) {
                    return new ListCell<Notepad>() {
                        @Override
                        protected void updateItem(Notepad item, boolean empty) {
                            super.updateItem(item, empty);

                            String style = "";
                            if (!empty && item != null) {
                                setText(item.getNotepadName());

                                switch (item.getNotepadPriority()) {
                                    case "Hoch":
                                        style = "-fx-background-color: red";
                                        break;
                                    case "Mittel":
                                        style = "-fx-background-color: yellow";
                                        break;
                                    case "Niedrig":
                                        style = "-fx-background-color: green";
                                        break;
                                    case "Neutral":
                                        style = "-fx-background-color: grey";
                                        break;
                                }
                            }
                            else {
                                setText("");
                            }
                            setStyle(style);
                        }
                    };
                }
            });
        }
    } catch(SQLException e) {
        e.printStackTrace();
    }
}
```

Additionally, my List is not refreshing after changing the Object within the same ObjectType. Example: Changing from Student1 to Student2. Changing between ObjectTypes themselves like Student1 to Group1 works. I think that the problem lays in the filter function of my ListCell.
Does someone have an idea? I'm struggeling with this problem for hours and can't figure it out!

Comment: Please provide a [mcve] that demonstrates the problem.

Comment: Generally, to figure out the problems easily, you can maintain your code in a clean and structured way. As I see from your code, the methods especially are too way long. And also, it is obvious that they are not accomplishing single tasks. Try to break them down into pieces and move the related operations into other classes. https://www.amazon.com/Clean-Code-Handbook-Software-Craftsmanship/dp/0132350882